# Batch File to Create Subfolders - Parameterized Function

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, subroutine

I'm trying to create the main directories with the help of `make_dir` function from `file1.bat` and sub-folders inside main folders from the same file.

**`file1.bat` Content:**

```
:make_dir
@IF NOT EXIST "Web_Files" (mkdir Web_Files)
ECHO Web_Files Directory Created

@IF NOT EXIST "C++ Files"   (mkdir C++ Files)
ECHO C++ Files Directory Created

EXIT /B 0

:make_sub_dir
@IF NOT EXIST "Web_Files"   (mkdir Web_Files)
ECHO Web_Files Directory Created

ECHO Creating %~2 Directory
@IF NOT EXIST "Web_Files\%~2" (mkdir Web_Files\%~2)
ECHO %~2 Directory Created

EXIT /B 0
```

From `file2.bat` I'm calling this function as:

```
SET "HTMLSubFolder=HTML"
SET "CSSSubFolder=CSS"
SET "JSSubFolder=JS"

call file1.bat make_dir
call file1.bat make_sub_dir %HTMLSubFolder%
call file1.bat make_sub_dir %CSSSubFolder%
call file1.bat make_sub_dir %JSSubFolder%
```

From `file2.bat` function call, Only main folders are created but the sub folders are not getting created.

Comment: The `call` command can either call another batch file or a label in the current one. To enter another batch file at a certain label you have to put some extra code. For instance, you could put at the beginning of `file1.bat` the line `goto :%~1`, so the first argument is treated as the target label...

Comment: Tto check for the existence of a directory, the syntax is `… EXIST "Dir Name\" …`, _(the back slash is important to ensure that a same name file is not confused as a directory)_. Also, you're telling the end use that a directory was created, but you have not determined whether that was the case. Just because you've told it, doesn't mean it has succeeded in doing so, therefore I would suggest that you take a look at that too.

Comment: @aschipfl can you please add your suggestion to the answer? didn't get you exactly what you trynna say.

Comment: @Compo I'm creating those dir only if they're not present earlier and yes, i'm using back slash.

Comment: @Compo, I used to use the `if exist "dir\"` method until I recently found out that this only reliably works for local drives, but it does not work when the target item is on a shared/mapped network drive (by `net use ...`), because the syntax with trailing backslash even reported `True` when the item is actually a file; not sure (yet) if that's also the case with drives mapped by `subst` or `pushd` (but I will test that), or if a specific constellation in my system is the root cause, but it made me switching to usage of `for %I in ("dir") do set "ATTR=%~aI" & if "!ATTR:~,1!"=="d" echo Dir!`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `call` command can either call another batch file or a label in the current one, but you are trying to specify both, the second of which is just passed as an argument to the first item, the batch file.

However, you can let the called script to use exactly that argument as a jump label:

- **`file1.bat`** (the called script; we could also name it the callee):

  ```cmd
  rem /* This takes the first argument as a jump label and continues execution there;
  rem    if it fails due to an non-existent or invalid label the script terminates: */
  goto :%~1 || exit /B 1

  :make_dir
  rem /* Here I removed `if exist` since `mkdir` cannot create an already existing
  rem    directory anyway; to suppress the error message I appended `2> nul`: */
  mkdir "Web_Files" 2> nul
  echo  "Web_Files" directory created

  mkdir "C++ Files" 2> nul
  echo "C++ Files" directory created

  exit /B 0

  :make_sub_dir
  rem /* Here I remove creation of "Web_Files" as the next command would create it
  rem    anyway when it does not yet exist (if command extensions are enabled): */
  echo Creating "%~2" directory
  mkdir "Web_Files\%~2" 2> nul
  echo "%~2" directory created

  exit /B 0
  ```
- **`file2.bat`** (the caller; almost unchanged except for quotation):

  ```cmd
  SET "HTMLSubFolder=HTML"
  SET "CSSSubFolder=CSS"
  SET "JSSubFolder=JS"

  rem // Here I quoted the second argument to protect spaces and poisonous characters:
  call file1.bat make_dir
  call file1.bat make_sub_dir "%HTMLSubFolder%"
  call file1.bat make_sub_dir "%CSSSubFolder%"
  call file1.bat make_sub_dir "%JSSubFolder%"
  ```

---

If I had to implement such an approach, I would change a few things though:

- let the callee interpret the first argument as a label only when it begins with `:`, so it might also receive other arguments for some further functionality;
- before jumping to that label, shift the remaining arguments so that there is no more difference in the argument references in the called routines compared to when calling them internally;

This is what I mean by that (to be applied to the callee, `file1.bat`):

```cmd
rem /* This takes the first argument as a jump label and continues execution there;
rem    if it fails due to an non-existent or invalid label the script terminates: */

rem // Store the first argument to a variable:
set "ARG1=%~1"
rem /* Check the first character of the first argument:
rem     * if it is a colon, the argument is interpreted as a jump label;
rem       so shift all further argument references back by one, so called routines
rem       do not have to take care of the first argument (the label) anymore, which
rem       is irrelevant there anyway; then try to jump and terminate upon an error;
rem    * if it is any other character or even blank (when no argument was given),
rem      any other activity can be triggered; for example, printing a message: */
if defined ARG1 if "%ARG1:~,1%"==":" shift /1 & goto %~1 || exit /B 1
rem /* This point is reached when the first argument does not begin with `:`;
rem    you can do some default actions here, or whatever else you like. */
exit /B 0


:make_dir
::(skipping the functional code here...)
exit /B 0


:make_sub_dir
rem // Here the first argument is referred to now:
echo Creating "%~1" directory
mkdir "Web_Files\%~1" 2> nul
echo "%~1" directory created

exit /B 0
```